# Functions with state

Tags: deep-learning, theano

I'm quite new to Theano and was reading the deep learning documentation here :

[deep learning Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html)

The function called accumulator with "inc" and state was explained really unclear, that I couldn't figure it out what happens that while the input is just one scalar, but you have both state and inc that have to be defined in the function definition. What happens every time you introduce a new number to the function?!!!